# Creating a TCP socket

Tags: networking, tcp-ip

I have been a Mac for a number of years and I am hoping to become a Penguin Fan for the purposes of technology development.

I am in the process of developing connected technology which requires TCP connection from vehicle mounted devices.

Can you advise on how I can create a TCP Socket please. I will need port 2095 to be open and to accept connections when the devices power up.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit more of a development tool question than a networking one?

If you just need to listen temporarily on port 2095 you can use the nc command on any linux machine.

To quickly listen for a single connection you could run:

```
nc -l 2095
```

This would accept a single connection, show you all of the characters sent from the 'client' and then close nc.

If you wanted to accept multiple connections:

```
nc -k -l 2095
```

^C to exit..

This is useful for testing, but if you're looking for a permanent / stable solution it will be development tool specific..